# How google Calendar authorization works

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to create an application that can share my schedule with all users in the same room using google calender api.

When authenticating with web client (oauth), do each user have the authority to view only the information of the user authenticated by his own browser?

For example, suppose user A and user B authenticate with oauth in their respective browsers.

In this case, does User B's browser have permission to view User A's calendar?
Or can I only view my own calendar?

If I want to do the above, do I have to use a backend to hold a per-user access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a little more complicated than that.

When user A run your application the user is displayed a consent screen. Asking them if they are willing to give your application access to their data.  Assuming the user gives your application access. Then Your application has access to access that users data.

When user B runs the application then the application will request user B for permission to access their data.

The application has access to user B's data and user A's data.  User A does not have access to user B's data.

What you could do is create a page where your application then displays data to both users from each others calendars.  If you want this to be a permanent thing then the application could also add user A to user Bs calendar and visa versa. Granting them each access to each other's data.

You may end up with some issues here as FAR As GDPR goes you will need to be sure that the two users realise that they are going to be sharing data for their calendars.   Does user A really want to show user B that they have an appointment for a hair transplant operation on monday for example.   This is private user data and you are treading on some sensitive data here.

Comment: Thanks!!!

If I want to create a page that displays data to both users, does User A store his calendar information in the application's database and User B retrieves User A's data stored in the application's database?

Comment: There is another way I am thinking.

First, after each user gets an access token with oauth, save the access token in the application DB.

User B then calls the backend with user A's userid as a parameter.

The backend calls calender api based on the access token associated with userid,
Gets the information for user A.

By returning the result to the front end, User B can see User A's information.

As you say, my application has to think more about GDPR

Comment: I would read though the [verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) processis. To do this you are going to need full calendar access, that's at least a sensitive scope.  Storing the data in your own system is going to leave you open for a lot of security concerns i wouldn't be surprised if google doesn't request a third party security elongation of your system.

Comment: Depending up how many users you have have you considered creating a internal calendar for each user and then controlling them from a central admin user, it would be even easer if you have a Google workspace account to do this.